# Parse Zabbix output format

Tags: python

I am using `pyzabbix` to interface with Zabbix and retrieve what I want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# import
import sys, subprocess, time, datetime, csv, platform
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI

# api/vars
url='http://172.18.64.100/zabbix'
zh = ZabbixAPI(url)
zh.login(user="Admin",password="xxxxxxxx")
groupid = sys.argv[1]

# get group from argv
group = zh.hostgroup.get(output="shorten", filter={"groupid": [groupid]}, monitored_hosts="1")

# get hosts from looping group above
hosts = zh.host.get(output="count", monitored_hosts="1", groupids=[x['groupid'] for x in group])

# print
for hostid in hosts:
    print hostid
    triggers = zh.trigger.get(filter={"hostid": hostid}, active="1", output=['description'])
    print triggers
```

So, the output is working, but i need to filter it and i am struggling:

```
{u'hostid': u'10166'}
[{u'triggerid': u'14138', u'description': u'Servidor Reiniciado'}, {u'triggerid': u'14139', u'description': u' Pin
 u'18082', u'description': u'Interface 7A'}, {u'triggerid': u'18083', u'description': u'Interface 7B'}, {u'trigger
scription': u'Interface 8A'}, {u'triggerid': u'18085', u'description': u'Interface 8B'}, {u'triggerid': u'18086',
nterface 9A'}, {u'triggerid': u'18087', u'description': u'Interface 9B'}, {u'triggerid': u'14140', u'description':
 {u'triggerid': u'14141', u'description': u'CPU 90% utilizada'}, {u'triggerid': u'14143', u'description': u' Sem c
SNMP por 30 minutos'}, {u'triggerid': u'23138', u'description': u'Servidor Reiniciado'}]
{u'hostid': u'10412'}
[{u'triggerid': u'22084', u'description': u'Agente Zabbix inoperante'}, {u'triggerid': u'22086', u'description': u
r Database (servi\xe7o_windows - McAfeeNetworkSecurityManagerDatabase)'}, {u'triggerid': u'22088', u'description':
ork Security Manager (servi\xe7o_windows - NetworkSecurityManager)'}, {u'triggerid': u'22090', u'description': u'C
, {u'triggerid': u'22091', u'description': u'Servidor Reiniciado'}, {u'triggerid': u'22092', u'description': u'Ser
 {u'triggerid': u'22122', u'description': u'Espa\xe7o em disco menor que 5% em C:'}, {u'triggerid': u'22124', u'de
xe7o em disco menor que 10% em C:'}, {u'triggerid': u'22123', u'description': u'Espa\xe7o em disco menor que 5% em
': u'22125', u'description': u'Espa\xe7o em disco menor que 10% em D:'}, {u'triggerid': u'22094', u'description':
\xedvel menor que 10%'}]
{u'hostid': u'10413'}
[{u'triggerid': u'22102', u'description': u'Agente Zabbix inoperante'}, {u'triggerid': u'22104', u'description': u
r Database (servi\xe7o_windows - McAfeeNetworkSecurityManagerDatabase)'}, {u'triggerid': u'22106', u'description':
ork Security Manager (servi\xe7o_windows - NetworkSecurityManager)'}, {u'triggerid': u'22108', u'description': u'C
, {u'triggerid': u'22109', u'description': u'Servidor Reiniciado'}, {u'triggerid': u'22110', u'description': u'Ser
 {u'triggerid': u'22132', u'description': u'Espa\xe7o em disco menor que 5% em C:'}, {u'triggerid': u'22134', u'de
xe7o em disco menor que 10% em C:'}, {u'triggerid': u'22133', u'description': u'Espa\xe7o em disco menor que 5% em
': u'22135', u'description': u'Espa\xe7o em disco menor que 10% em D:'}, {u'triggerid': u'22112', u'description':
\xedvel menor que 10%'}]
```

I just want the "hostid" and the "description" part of the output, i mean:

```
hostid - 10166
Servidor Reiniciado
Ping
Interface 7A
Interface 7B
...

hostid - 10412
Agente Zabbix inoperante
...
...
```

Comment: You mean that you need to get `description` field from all `triggers` and concatenate them to one string?

Comment: yes, i just need to get the "description" part and concatenate for the first host, and then for the second, thanks !

Comment: I just put the example, but the output does not need to be like that exactly, as long it concatenates just the description its fine for me :)

Comment: SO isn't here to write code for you. *Put some effort in*, then return with a [mcve] if you get stuck.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, i don't want you to write the code for me, i just asked for a help, if it's not right for you, just don't answer :(. I said im not a expert and i am sure you already were im my position, but thanks anyway. I tried many things, but none printed that, i tried another loop inside.

Comment: Well then give an example of **that code**; cut away the rest of the question and focus on the specific problem you had. We were all learners once, but not all of us expected free tutorials from SO.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, i just loop again 
I know its ugly, but well, it's fine for now :)

I've put another loop inside #print part:

```
for hostid in hosts:
   # triggers = zh.trigger.get(hostids=[x['hostid'] for x in hosts], active="1", selectHosts="1")
    print hostid
    triggers = zh.trigger.get(filter={"hostid": hostid}, active="1", output=['description'])
    for description in triggers:
        print description
```

And i got what i want:

```
{u'hostid': u'10166'}
{u'triggerid': u'14138', u'description': u'Servidor Reiniciado'}
{u'triggerid': u'14139', u'description': u' Ping'}
{u'triggerid': u'18082', u'description': u'Interface 7A'}
{u'triggerid': u'18083', u'description': u'Interface 7B'}
{u'triggerid': u'18084', u'description': u'Interface 8A'}
{u'triggerid': u'18085', u'description': u'Interface 8B'}
{u'triggerid': u'18086', u'description': u'Interface 9A'}
{u'triggerid': u'18087', u'description': u'Interface 9B'}
{u'triggerid': u'14140', u'description': u'System Health'}
{u'triggerid': u'14141', u'description': u'CPU 90% utilizada'}
{u'triggerid': u'14143', u'description': u' Sem coleta de dados via SNMP por 30 minutos'}
{u'triggerid': u'23138', u'description': u'Servidor Reiniciado'}
{u'hostid': u'10412'}
{u'triggerid': u'22084', u'description': u'Agente Zabbix inoperante'}
{u'triggerid': u'22086', u'description': u' McAfee IPS Manager Database (servi\xe7o_windows - McAfeeNetworkSecurit
{u'triggerid': u'22088', u'description': u' McAfee IPS Network Security Manager (servi\xe7o_windows - NetworkSecur
{u'triggerid': u'22090', u'description': u'CPU 100% utilizada'}
{u'triggerid': u'22091', u'description': u'Servidor Reiniciado'}
{u'triggerid': u'22092', u'description': u'Servidor Reiniciado'}
{u'triggerid': u'22122', u'description': u'Espa\xe7o em disco menor que 5% em C:'}
{u'triggerid': u'22124', u'description': u'Espa\xe7o em disco menor que 10% em C:'}
{u'triggerid': u'22123', u'description': u'Espa\xe7o em disco menor que 5% em D:'}
{u'triggerid': u'22125', u'description': u'Espa\xe7o em disco menor que 10% em D:'}
{u'triggerid': u'22094', u'description': u'Mem\xf3ria dispon\xedvel menor que 10%'}
```

Thanks all.